# Graphic short stories series about a boy falling through a hole which sends him to a fantasy world of monsters and magic?

Tags: story-identification, magic

Some details I remember:

1. Was around in early-mid 90's, the series came out in weekly installments (something you could get from your newsagent).
2. The story begins when a schoolboy falls into a hole in the ground on his way home from school, and is transported to another world where his meets a warrior.
3. I think his quest is to find his way back home but along the way meets other warriors/wizards, which are on quests of their own.
4. In one installment he meets massive scorpions, in another he meets a cyclops/abominable snowman
5. Each installment was published similar to a short, graphic magazine-sized book.
6. I think the title of the series contained the word 'world' as in 'Neverworld' or 'Everworld'.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90346/seeking-a-novel-containing-the-word-ever-in-the-title-teens-fall-asleep-and-a (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 4):

There is the Everworld series of twelve books by K. A. Applegate that started in 1999. It is much the same theme, but some details do not fit your description. You could be mixing different stories, either on the details of the story, or on the name of the series.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a bit like *[Mighty Max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mighty_Max_%28TV_series%29)*, which was a children's television cartoon in 1993-1994.  The Wikipedia article indicated that there was a spinoff of 10 comic books.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like "The Ancestral Trail". My brother was mad on these, I was pretty keen myself. Wikipedia has a write up and there's plenty of covers in google images.

Comment: Your answer would be improved if you included some of these details you mention