# Seeking a novel containing the word "ever" in the title; Teens fall asleep and awake in a medieval fantasy world

Tags: story-identification

I read a book 12 years ago.  I believe it had Ever on its name.

It was about these high schoolers that went to sleep and woke up in a world of magic or medieval. I do know that when they went to sleep that would travel back and forth. I know it's not much but if you can help thank you.

Comment: What about the world was magical? Do you remember anything about the high schoolers (age, gender, names)? What was the plot? Was there a villain? Was this a young-adult fantasy or something more mature? Was the "Ever" part of the name at the end or the beginning?

Comment: You had the book marked as "science fiction" in your original question title. Was there anything sci-fi about the book?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Joey-Cola-Warriors-Fantasy-Series-ebook/dp/B00LLUGAP2 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possibly the [Everworld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everworld) series by K. A. Applegate.  It's YA and it's about teenagers and it's fantasy and it has Ever in the title, which meets most of the admittedly limited criteria!

> David's life was pretty normal. School. Friends. Girlfriend. Actually,
>   Senna was probably the oddest aspect of his life. She was beautiful.
>   Smart. But there was something very different about her. Something
>   strange.
>
> And on the day it began, everything happened so quickly. One moment,
>   Senna was with him. The next, she was swallowed up by the earth, her
>   screams echoing from far, far away. David couldn't just let her go.
>   Neither could the others. His friends and hers. So, they followed. And
>   found themselves in a world they could have never imagined.
>
> Now they have to find Senna and get home without losing their lives.
>   Or their minds. Or both...

[Published](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/279673.Search_for_Senna) in 1999 so the date range is also close.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be "[Midrealm](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18159788-midrealm)" by Garrett Robinson? It's much too late (2013) but the plot sounds astoundingly similar...

> What if you and your friends went to another world every time you went
>   to sleep?
>
> What if you spent half your life here, in our world, and the other
>   half battling for mankind’s survival against foes too terrible to be
>   real?
>
> And what if you could never tell anyone?
>
> This is reality for the Realm Keepers: six people from Earth thrust
>   into a terrifying war between Midrealm and Chaos. Plucked from their
>   ordinary lives and given extraordinary powers, they’re the only thing
>   standing between our world and destruction.

...

> Midrealm is a story about six teenagers who are in detention one day
>   and pass out. They wake up in another world, where they are the Realm
>   Keepers, wizards with incredible powers. Each Realm Keeper has a
>   different element to control. The world is threatened by an evil
>   wizard called Terrence that they need to battle, to save both Midrealm
>   (the fantasy world) and Earth.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Stravaganza. I was looking for this forever and when I finally remembered one kid had cancer I was able to find it. Anyway it's possible you were thinking of everworld but if not its definitely this

Comment: Why do you think this is the book? Do you have any details (plot summary, reviews, etc) that you could add to your answer?

Comment: The original poster has already confirmed that *Everworld* **is** the answer.