# Earth boy goes to a magical fantasy world when he sleeps

Tags: story-identification, warfare

Boy is on Earth but when he sleeps he goes to a different world. Both worlds' stories carry on over the book and they connect at the end. It starts with the boy in a monastery and in a small apartment on earth but strangers arrive to get a map decoded in his sleep. He goes on a quest then with these strangers to find hidden ancient heirlooms of their ruling family. Boy is from on of the ruling elite family's able to exist in both worlds we meet a alien guide who offers to teach the boy as a teacher .

In the end of the book he brings a gun from Earth to the magic world.

He is attacked by a dragon but heals the damage, and later he makes a healing deal with the dragon to heal him in the future.

it was a book I read in the 90's but I forget its name I like to read it again

Comment: Any out-of-universe details you can remember will help; was this a book/movie/comic? When did you read/see it? Was it recent or older when you read/saw it?

Comment: Could it be one of the answer listed in the previous question at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90346/seeking-a-novel-containing-the-word-ever-in-the-title-teens-fall-asleep-and-a ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember the dragon, but the rest sounds like 'Pawns Dream' by Eric Nylund. From the [Amazon description](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pawns-Dream-Eric-Nylund-ebook/dp/B00T5GUNUW):

> To escape a tedious life working as a convenience store clerk and caring for his mentally ill mother, Roland Pritchard dreams. Every night he dreams of a magical realm called Meredin. In that world, Roland is a scholar of Meredin’s ancient history, toiling away at a monastic life in an isolated abbey. His one escape from this dreary existence? Every night the young acolyte Roland dreams of a fantastic and strange world called Earth.
>
> And so it goes, night after night, dream after dream, until Roland's estranged cousins discover him. They reveal the truth: that Earth and Meredin are equally real, that Roland is a member of the royal Dreaming Families, and that his life in both worlds is in peril.
>
> Traveling between realms, Roland must dodge assassins and stop a secret war that threatens the two worlds. To do so he must master his latent magical talent, a strange sorcery that combines pairs of opposites (fire and water, earth and water, or in Roland’s case, life and death) to produce potent dreaming magics.